# Poincaré inequality for $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n},$ open, connected and limited. Then exist $c=c(\Omega)>0$ such that
$$\int_{\Omega}|u|^2 dx  \leq c\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2 dx,$$
for all $u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega).$

In this case, diam($\Omega)<\infty.$ Then $\Omega\subset \{(x_{1},\dots,x_{n} | \ |x_{1}|<\text{diam}(\Omega)\}.$ Therefore exist $c>0$ such that
$$\int_{\Omega}|u|^2 dx  \leq c\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2 dx,$$ for all $u\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega).$

But how to make it for $u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)?$ I know that $C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega).$ I think that we can make it by approximation, but I couldn't.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and let $u_n \to u$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, with $u_n \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$. By the statement for smooth functions, we have
$$
\int_\Omega |u_n|^2 \leq C \int_\Omega |\nabla u_n|^2
$$
for each $n$. What happens if we take a limit?

Comment: So, in this case can I apply dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: One can't apply dominated convergence, because there is no pointwise convergence happening - it's convergence in $H_0^1$. So by the reverse triangle inequality $|\|u_n\|_{H^1_0} - \|u\|_{H^1_0}| \leq \|u_n - u\|_{H^1_0} \to 0$. In particular $\|u_n\|_{L^2} \to \|u\|_{L^2}$, and $\|\nabla  u_n\|_{L^2} \to \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: Oh! Thank you, sir. Now I can understand! Thank you so much!!